# Make Javascript write on page after submit button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, submit

Here is a bit of code I have sourced from w3schools which shows that whenever a name is over 10 characters, the page should add a bit of text, in this case, it should add on "hi", but instead, it removes everything from the page and goes onto a new page and only displays "hi". How can I resolve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  Name (max 10 characters): <input type="text" id="fname" size="20" name="fname"><br>
  Age (from 1 to 100): <input type="text" id="age" size="20" name="age"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" size="20" name="mail"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var at = document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@");
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    submitOK = "true";

    if (fname.length > 10) {
        document.write("hi");
    } 

    if (isNaN(age) || age < 1 || age > 100) {
        alert("The age must be a number between 1 and 100");
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (at == -1) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail!");
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (submitOK == "false") {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, don't use [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write). If you read the nice orange text at the top of the documentation, you'll see why:

> Note: as `document.write` writes to the document **stream**, calling `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open`, [which will clear the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#Notes).

`document.write()` should only be used while a page is loading, to ouput while it's creating the webpage, and should not be used afterwards. Consider creating a div, and writing to there instead:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var at = document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@");
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    submitOK = "true";

    if (fname.length > 10) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Fname is > 10!';
    } 

    if (isNaN(age) || age < 1 || age > 100) {
        alert("The age must be a number between 1 and 100");
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (at == -1) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail!");
        submitOK = "false";
    }

    if (submitOK == "false") {
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Submitted Successfully!');
        return false; // Returning false here just for SO Code Snippet
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  Name (max 10 characters): <input type="text" id="fname" size="20" name="fname"><br>
  Age (from 1 to 100): <input type="text" id="age" size="20" name="age"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" size="20" name="mail"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

Additionally, I notice you're setting `submitOK = "true"`. Javascript does have [booleans](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) (See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean) also). Why not use that instead?

```
submitOK = true;

if (fname.length < 10) {
    alert('Your name should be more than 10 characters');
    submitOK = false;
}

if (submitOK) { // Same as "if (submitOK == true)"
    //Good to go
}
```